# What does UX tag mean?

Tags: ux

I bet U means "Users", but X? When I see the tag I think of *Unix.

There is no info on the tag and its used in a lot of questions.

Comment: Questions about the site should be directed at http://meta.ui.stackexchange.com - don't repost I've started the migration process.

Comment: Voted to close, but created a wiki for the ux tag while I was at it: http://ui.stackexchange.com/tags/ux/info

Comment: That's the first time I've seen it written *Unix, usually it's written as either Unix or *nix. Bravo for the combination ;)

Answer (score 5):

UX stands for **U**ser e**X**perience.

Comment: I came accross this word for the first time back a few years ago on the MSDN site when I came across the Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx

Answer (score -1):

yes it means user experience in other words "the philosophy of a webpage) ;)